# databinding - can't find BR class

Tags: java, android, android-databinding

I'm using android databinding, using [this post][1] as a guide. I realize it's not targeting androidx databinding, but I'm not using androidx on my project yet, but am using the latest android support libraries.

Anyways, I have my ViewModel extending BaseObservable. The BR class is being generated and appears correct. e.g. I can ctrl-click on BR.stateText and I'm navigated to teh genreated class which is in `[app]\build\generated\ap_generated_sources\debug\com.android.databinding.library.baseAdapters\BR`. But, IntelliJ seems to not understand that the class acutally exists when I go to compile it.

```
import android.databinding.BaseObservable;
import android.databinding.Bindable;
import com.android.databinding.library.baseAdapters.BR;

public class MyViewModel extends BaseObservable {

    public MyViewModel() {
        mStateText = "DEFAULT_TEXT_123";
    }

    @Bindable
    private String mStateText = null;

    public String getStateText() {
        return mStateText;
    }

    public void setStateText(String stateText) {
        mStateText = stateText;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.stateText);
    }
}
```

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
                name="viewModel"
                type="my.org.MyViewModel "/>
    </data>

...


        <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_row="1" android:layout_column="1"
                android:id="@+id/system_state_btn"
                android:text="@{viewModel.stateText}"/>
```

Fragment:

````
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        MainStatusBinding activityMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(getActivity(), R.layout.main_status);
        activityMainBinding.setViewModel(new MyViewModel());
        activityMainBinding.executePendingBindings();

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_status, container, false);
    ...
    ```
.
````

error: cannot find symbol
import com.android.databinding.library.baseAdapters.BR;
                                                   ^
  symbol:   class BR
  location: package com.android.databinding.library.baseAdapters

```
What is wrong with my setup that's causing IntelliJ to not recognize the class exists? Note, this fails for me when building on the commandline, so it's not specific to IntelliJ.

IntelliJ: 2020.1

Gradle wrapper: 6.3

android build tools: 28.0.3

android gradle plugin: 3.5.0

  [1]: https://www.journaldev.com/20292/android-mvvm-design-pattern
```

Comment: Hello! Podrías agregar la clase de tu activity y de tu xml para poder ayudarte :)

Comment: added layout and fragment code

Answer (score 0):

The `BR` class that is generated should be at the root package of your project, you're importing the wrong one. Also the `@Bindable` annotation should go on the public getter, not the private backing field.

Comment: Changed my import to specify the import [root-package].BR, and I don't see errors in the IDE, but at compilation, it fails to find the Br class. I also moved my @Bindable as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

**Just restart the android studio, it would work.**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try to resolve the issue by adding the namespace.

```
 android {
       //...
        namespace = "com.your.package"
        android.buildFeatures.dataBinding = true
    }
```